# Why is a Vanishing Vector Field $\Rightarrow$ Discontinuous Frame?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

I'm reading Tu's Introduction to Manifolds section on oreintablility.

On an orientable manifold, if any vector field vanishes at a point $p$ (e.g. $S^2$), then the *global frame* $(X_1,X_2)$ that represents the orientation is necessarily discontinuous.

I think this is true because for an open set $U$ containing $p$, the orientation equivalence classes $[(X_{1,q},X_{2,q})]$ can't all be the same because $T_pM=\{0\}$, which has it's own convention $+$ or $-$ which is incompatible with $+[(X_{1,q},X_{2,q})]$ and $-[(X_{1,q},X_{2,q})]$

Is this correct, and is this conevention for orientation of $\{0\}$ the most common?

Comment: Where did you see the claim that a vector field that vanishes at some point is discontinuous? Either the source is wrong or you've misquoted it (perhaps by omitting some hypothesis).

Comment: Oh, you are right, I misread. I put continuous vector field instead of continuous frame. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a continuous global frame for the tangent bundle, then the vector fields that constitute the frame would be linearly independent at  every point (because they form a basis for the tangent space at that point).  In particular, none of them can vanish at any point.

This doesn't actually have much to do with tangent bundles.  The same argument shows that, for an arbitrary vector bundle, if each continuous global section vanishes somewhere, then there cannot be a continuous global frame.

Comment: Why does the frame need to be continuous for $(X_p,Y_p)$ to span $T_pM$? My book only defines a continuous global frame in terms of orientation of $T_pM$: $(X,Y)$ is a continuous global frame if for every $x\in M$, the orientation of $T_xM$ is given by the equivalence classes $[(X_x,Y_x)]$ of orientations of $T_xM$, where $X, Y$ are continuous  vector fields. Is this consistent with what you wrote?

Comment: Continuity of the frame is not needed in order to ensure that the vectors span the tangent space, but it is needed to ensure that the constituent vector fields are continuous so that your assumption (about their having zeros somewhere) applies. What you quoted from the book seems to be the very special case of what I wrote, where the manifold is 2-dimensional and the frame is intended to specify the orientation.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)